# How do I gain read access to another user's directory?

Tags: files, security

I have two users: Alice and Bob. They both belong to the group staff. I want to be able to list the content of the directory `/home/alice/Private/` when I'm logged in as the user Bob. As it is now Bob has no access to `/home/alice/Private/`. Assuming I need some sort of an attack script or a program to do this. What would that look like?

Comment: first, hack root. then abuse root's access privileges to snoop on alice's private files.

Comment: Thinking I should use a sort of Confused-deputy attack, but can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Would be interesting to know if you found a way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to do is not possible without either elevated privileges or subverting unix security. You have four options:

- Gain access legitimately by appealing to the system administrator
- Gain access legitimately by appealing to the user, Alice
- Find a backdoor in Unix filesystem security
- Leverage physical access (or, if it's a virtual machine, leverage access from the host)

If you choose for the third option and succeed, depending on your moral compass, you should report the security flaw to the maintainers of the operating system. Here's some documentation to get you started: https://www.giac.org/paper/gsec/2235/quest-root-hacker-techniques-unix-security/103808

Comment: Thanks for the extra information, Gilles. And congratulations on a successful edit. Even though a comment would have sufficed, you saw that, in your wisdom, adding another bullet to my answer contributed so, so much. That said, "leveraging physical access" to a system is a valid point. Please ask before editing answers. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If you have root access then you can change the R/w Mode using.

**$ sudo chmod 777 Private.file**   //It will give you all permissions to read write and execute.

And also if you want you can change the ownership too.

**$ sudo chown Bob:Bob Privat.file** //it will change ownership of the file, and now the owner is Bob

For more check

**$man chmod**

**$man chown**

Comment: I don't have root access.

Comment: Straight answer : Than it is not easy to attack the private folder with out permission. :)